# Find value that is not equal to another value

Tags: sql

Hi all i'm currently doing some SQL homework and am looking for a push in the right direction.
I need to display a list of directors that have never worked in a paramount picture movie.

```
select distinct directorID
from movieinfo natural join directinfo
where studio <> 'Paramount Picture';
```

This displays both directors who never have, as well as directors who have worked for paramount and also done another job with someone else.

I thought maybe an EXISTS sub query would help me but i ended up with the exact same result.

Would anyone know a way to check if directer EVER worked with paramount and to cross them off the list?

EDIT**
DirectorID does not belong in both tables.
directinfo(mvid, directorID)
movieinfo(mvid, title, rating, year, length, studio)

Comment: what table does `directorID` and `studio` belongs?

Comment: You have to specify join condition. You have where condition .... but that is not the join condition.... means you have to specify something which is common b/w movieinfo and direcinfo tables and also do the subquery .. where you pull all director Ids who did work in paramount picture ... like  ---where movieinfo.DirectorID = directinfo.DirectorID and directorInfo.Director ID not IN (select distinct directorID from directorinfo where studeio = 'Paramount Picture');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    directinfo a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    movieinfo b
            WHERE   a.directorID = b.directorID AND
                    b.studio <> 'Paramount Picture'
        )
```

this assumes that column `studio` belong on table `movieinfo` and both tables contains `directorID`.

Another way is to use `LEFT JOIN...IS NULL`,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    directinfo a
        LEFT JOIN movieinfo b
            ON  a.directorID = b.directorID AND
                b.studio <> 'Paramount Picture'
WHERE   b.directorID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something such as the following:

```
SELECT directorID FROM directinfo WHERE directorID NOT IN 
    (SELECT directorID FROM movieinfo WHERE studio='Paramount Picture');
```

This will give you all director IDs which are not involved in the Paramount Picture studio.

Edit: Removed 2nd answer which was wrong.

Comment: Your second query would return all directors who were at least once involved in a studio unlike Paramount Picture studio. And thats wrong.

Comment: The issue with this is that it shows directors who have worked with multiple people including paramount.

Comment: +1 on the first suggestion. However, I don't think there's any sense in suggesting alternatives to the OP's attempt if it didn't work for them.