# List all A that does not exist in condition

Tags: sql

So i have to - List the directorID of directors who have never directed movies produced in 
'Paramount Picture'.

the tables are
Movieinfo(mvid, title, rating, year, length, studio)
directinfo(mvid, directorID)

```
select distinct directorID
from movieinfo natural join directinfo
where studio <> 'Paramount Picture';
```

Does not work because it shows directors that have done films with paramount and then films without paramount. So i tried using exists, not exists, in, not in, but i'm constantly getting directors who have worked with paramount previously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find value that is not equal to another value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766742/find-value-that-is-not-equal-to-another-value)

Comment: All of those responses were giving incorrect answers and then it died.

Comment: and all the answers here are the same with the previous one.

Comment: yes, all of which are wrong :(

Comment: because you didn't explained well. best way you do is to give sample records and your desired result. try it `:)`

Comment: the "problem" was that we all forgot  that directinfo is just a "relationship" table...

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct d.directorID
from directinfo as d
where d.directorId not in
                  (select distinct d1.directorId 
                  from movieinfo as m
                  inner join directinfo as d1 on d1.mvid = m.mvid
                  where m.studio =  'Paramount Picture');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am confused however about the 'd' and 'm' placement, are these shortcuts to say "directinfo" and "movieinfo"?

Comment: @Ryan yes. They are `alias`

Comment: I tried to write it out in full form but it would error in oracle SQL

Comment: @Ryan Could you please add "as" before the aliases, it makes it a bit nicer for referencing this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 select distinct directorid from 
  directorinfo where 
  mvid not in 
( select mvid from movieinfo where studio<>'paramount')
```

Comment: That shows all directors which have made any movie outside paramount, but not excludes those who have also made one at paramount.

Comment: List the directorID of directors who have never directed movies produced in 'Paramount Picture'. What does it mean? Am I reading it totally wrong?

Comment: You select all movies outside paramount and as such look for directors never directed outside paramount. This query also will be quite slow because the database has to manage that potentially long list of movies outside paramount against every entry of directorinfo.